# Array to string conversion error while file upload,Error is displaying but not success data

Tags: codeigniter-3

My code is working fine on upload fail but on upload success error is thrown as undefined variable: data. Can anyone help me how I can pass the success data to view

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('Pdf', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

public function do_upload()
{
    if($this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $data['success']= $this->upload->data();
    }
    else
    {
        $data['error'] =  $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
}
```

**view:**

```
 <?php echo $error;?>
 <?php echo $data["file_name"];?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you upload using `$this->upload->data()`, you are **get an Array** as a result, *not a variable or string.*

e.g Below is an result array from Image upload.

```
Array
(
    [file_name] => 
    [file_type] => 
    [file_path] => 
    [full_path] => 
    [raw_name] => 
    [orig_name] => 
    [client_name] => 
    [file_ext] => 
    [file_size] => 
    [is_image] => 
    [image_width] => 
    [image_height] => 
    [image_type] => 
    [image_size_str] => 
)
```

And here you are printing an array using echo instead of print_r.

**echo** is used to give output the data.

**print_r** is used to print array.

So solution for this "Array to string conversion error while file upload" is,

Change `echo $data["file_name"];` ==> `print_r($data);` or `print_r($data['success'])`